# snmpGetVariableBindings returning null and ASN1_ERROR_ERR when ObjectIDList size > 8

Tags: java, snmp, mib, oid

I am trying to query a device for specific sensors, and get ASN1_ERROR_ERR depending on the number of oids that I specify.  Here is the code where the problem is.

```
target.setObjectIDList(objID);
try {
    resultArray= target.snmpGetVariableBindings();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.logError(ex.getMessage());
}
```

The 'target' variable is a com.adventnet.snmp.beans.SnmpTarget and the objID is String array of oids.  The list of oids are all coming from the same MIB table.  When I specify 8 of them, it works: resultArray is non-null, contains the expected values, and target.getErrorCode() returns 0 (No Error).  When I specify 9 oids, resultArray is null and target.getErrorCode() is 50 (which is ASN1_ERROR_ERR: 'SNMP ASN1Error encountered due to Illegal SNMP packet received from [my device's ip]).  It doesn't seem to matter which oids I specify, and each work if specified on their own.

Here is an example of the oids I send in:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.2
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.3
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.4
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.5
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.6
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.7
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.8
```

as soon as I add

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.19536.10.1.3.1.1.12.1.9
```

to the list is when it doesn't work.  Though I can use oids 2-9 fine and then add 10 and it doesn't work.

Any thoughts as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a SNMP **response with packet size exceeded**:

- when invoked with the 8 OIDs, your AdventNet library creates a request made of a UDP packet encapsulated in an IP datagram of 236 bytes;
- when you add a ninth OID, the IP datagram has 22 more bytes.

But the SNMP response is bigger than the request: it includes a value for each requested OID. **Then, your snmp remote agent can not put all the requested responses in the UDP response, when you add too much OIDs in a single request**. Thus, according to RFC-1157, **it adds an error indicator in the response packet**: *If the size of the GetResponse-PDU generated as described below would exceed a local limitation, then the receiving entity sends to the originator of the received message the GetResponse-PDU of identical form, except that the value of the error-status field is tooBig, and the value of the error-index field is zero.*